# can't decode QR codes from OpenCV image after it has been converted to PIL

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, zbar

I've been using OpenCV methods to get images from my camera.  I'd like to decode QR codes from those images using the zbar library, but after I convert the images to PIL to be processed by zbar, it doesn't seem like the decoding is working.

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import zbar
from PIL import Image


cv.NamedWindow("camera", 1)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)

while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    cv.ShowImage("camera", img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break

    # create a reader
    scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()

    # configure the reader
    scanner.parse_config('enable')

    # obtain image data
    pil = Image.fromstring("L", cv.GetSize(img), img.tostring())
    width, height = pil.size
    raw = pil.tostring()

    # wrap image data
    image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)

    # scan the image for barcodes
    scanner.scan(image)

    # extract results
    for symbol in image:
        # do something useful with results
        print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data


cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to convert the OpenCV image to a PIL image in order to use it with zbar... you can go straight from an OpenCV image to zbar and avoid using PIL completely.

Now I don't know how you do this when the image source is from a camera, but if you load an image from disk, all you have to do is this:

```python
cv_img = cv.LoadImageM(image, cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
width = cv_img.width
height = cv_img.height
raw = cv_img.tostring()

# wrap image data
image = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', raw)

# scan the image for barcodes
scanner.scan(image)

# extract results
for symbol in image:
    # do something useful with results
    print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data
```

It appears you basically have to do the following for this to work:

- Use LoadImageM instead of LoadImage
- Make sure the image is grayscale so use cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in python I suggest you take a look at [SimpleCV](http://www.simplecv.org/). You can either crib our implementation of bar code reading or use the library yourself. [Here is the source](https://github.com/ingenuitas/SimpleCV/blob/develop/SimpleCV/ImageClass.py#L4577) for pulling  barcodes out with zbar.

Comment: I'd like to avoid using simple CV just because I've been using open CV for other purposes and I'd rather not re implement the functionality I've done.  There is a simple CV method that I'd like to find the equivalent of though. it's the .getpil() method.

Comment: SimpleCV should interoperate just fine with OpenCV (as it is built on top of OpenCV), your only concerns would be the dependencies. If you can handle the deps you should be fine.

Comment: Well it's more that I'm doing something with an open CV captured image like color tracking and I need to use that same image to do my decoding.